# I used inline editing now in jqgrid and I want two column to update in database?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, textbox, updating

I have Jqgrid And inline editing for Activity Name and Credit Hours column.I also have one exyernal button Submit credit.And on that button I want to save Activity Name and Credit Hours entries in database.How can I do this.My grid code is following:
`$("#cmehoursgrid").jqGrid({ //set your grid id
  datatype:"local",
  colNames:['ID','First Name','Last Name','NPI','Activity Name','Credit Hours'], //define column names
            colModel:[
                  {name:'id', index:'id', key: true,width:50,editable: false},
                  {name:'firstName', index:'firstName',key: true,width:50,editable: false},
                  {name:'lastName', index:'lastName', key: true,width:50,editable: false},
                  {name:'npi', index:'npi', key: true,width:50,editable: false},
                  {name:'activity_name', index:'activity_name', key: true,width:50,editable: true,edittype:"text"},
                  {name:'credit_hours', index:'credit_hours', key: true,width:50,editable: true, edittype: 'text'},
            ], //define column models 
            pager: '#cmehourspager', //set your pager div id
            multiSort:true,
            sortable:true,
            loadonce :true,
            rownum:5,
            width:710,
            height:300,
            scrollOffset: 1,
            cellEdit: true,
            editurl: '',
            shrinkToFit:true,
            sortname: 'id', //the column according to which data is to be sorted; optional
            viewrecords: true, //if true, displays the total number of records, etc. as: "View X to Y out of Z” optional
            gridview: true,
            sortorder: "desc", //sort order; optional
            caption:"Update CME Hours" //title of grid

      });`
and I have popup on button click

```
 <div id="cmedialog" title="Dialog Title">
    <table id="cmehoursgrid"></table>
    <div id="cmehourspager"></div>
    <button id="submitcredit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right submitcredit" type="button">Submit Credits</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What you have tried so far, what error you getting or where you stuck up in the code? Or Just have a look and try something from here http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html then update the question and you will get quick response.

Comment: I have edited the question again to understand more.